# MySQL: Can an INNODB table be entirely locked?

Tags: mysql, innodb

If I run:

```
LOCK TABLE table1, table2 READ
// DO STUFF
UNLOCK TABLES
```

Will this block all other sessions from accessing table1 and table2 if the table type is INNODB? If not, how do I then lock the table in INNODB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this useful article here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/07/31/innodb-table-locks/

Explicitly locking tables on MySQL level will prevent tables from being accessed and will not show up in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. It is a good practice not to use `LOCK TABLES` when you’re using Innodb Tables from performance persepctive, because Innodb uses row level locks.

Comment: But then how do you lock an entire table, or is the solution to move away from innodb?

Comment: You can have mixed table engines in the same database, so you can easily switch some of your tables to use MyISAM.